# XmlSerializer and xsd:list

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, xmlserializer, xsd.exe

Is there an out-of-the-box way to deal with `<xsd:list>` in XmlSerializer ?

In my case I got a list of `double`, something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="PositionType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="doubleList">
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="doubleList">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:double"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="Test" type="PositionType"/>
```

An instance may look like this:  `<pos>10.3 20.2 -2.4</pos>`

I tried to make xsd.exe reveal some secrets, but it generated this.. which fails:

```
private double[] textField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
public double[] Text {
    get {
        return this.textField;
    }
    set {
        this.textField = value;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
  System.InvalidOperationException: Member 'Text' cannot be encoded using the XmlText attribute. You may use the XmlText attribute to encode primitives, enumerations, arrays of strings, or arrays of XmlNode.
```

Note that I am using existing schemas and have no way to influence design.

Comment: Are you saying that the generated class which is based on the xsd is  generated incorrectly or have you altered the generated class?